# How to properly use @angular/flex-layout?

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I am creating a web app using [@angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout).

I try to have a 5% margin left and right when the screen is smaller than 600px (`xs`). It is working correctly on larger screens (when there is a `fxLayout="row"`-layout), but not in the `xs` and `fxLayout="column"`-situation.

[Here is a demonstration in Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/rqu6lnlKx04m1U4oDQE7?p=preview)

**Question**: How to make the `div`'s  *not* fill the remaining space to the right, but make them take only 90% with a 5% offset left and right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end, I used a similar aproach as @Nehal but instead of `ngStyle.xs` I used `ngClass.xs` and got it working fine.

```
<div fxLayout.xs="column"
     fxLayout.gt-xs="row"
     fxFlex.xs="grow"
     fxFlex.gt-xs="grow">
  <div ngClass.xs="section-title-xs-margin"
       fxFlex.xs="90"
       fxFlex.gt-xs="25"
       fxFlex.gt-sm="20"
       fxFlexOffset.xs="5"
       fxFlexOffset.gt-xs="5"
       fxFlexOffset.gt-sm="10">
    Left / Top
  </div>
  <div ngClass.xs="content-xs-margin"
       fxFlex.xs="90"
       fxFlex.gt-xs="63"
       fxFlex.gt-sm="55"
       fxFlexOffset.xs="5"
       fxFlexOffset.gt-xs="2"
       fxFlexOffset.gt-sm="5">
    Right / Bottom
  </div>
</div>
```

And in CSS:

```
.section-title-xs-margin {
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.content-xs-margin {
  margin-right: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I edited your plunker and got it to work using `[ngStyle.xs]`.

code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test-app',
  template: `
  <div fxLayout.xs="column"
     fxLayout.gt-xs="row"
     class="containerX"
     [ngStyle.xs]="{'width.%': 90, 'margin-left.%': 5, 'margin-right.%': 5}"
     style="background-color: grey">
    <div style="background-color: blue"
         fxFlex.xs="90"
         fxFlex.gt-xs="25"
         fxFlex.gt-sm="20"
         fxFlexOffset="5"
         fxFlexOffset.gt-xs="5"
         fxFlexOffset.gt-sm="10">
      Left / Top
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: red"
         fxFlex.xs="90"
         fxFlex.gt-xs="63"
         fxFlex.gt-sm="55"
         fxFlexOffset="5"
         fxFlexOffset.gt-xs="2"
         fxFlexOffset.gt-sm="5">
      Right / Bottom
    </div>
</div>
`,
  styles: [`
    .containerX {
      border: solid 1px #b6b6b6;
      background: skyblue;
      height: 200px;
      width: 100%;
    }`
]
})
export class TestApp {

}
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/2ZnnzJcYsAhUZU1EAmS4?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: It dind't work properly with your aproach. For some reason, the `xs`-Styles were not applied to the `div`'s. I found a solution myself in the meantime using `ngClass.xs`. Thanks for your time!